# why can i kill a process of state D in debian?

Tags: c, linux, process, debian

They say we can`t kill a process of state D, but I just did, why?

[image: picture here]

```
 ps aux | grep ./a
aa       21431  0.0  0.0   4224  1044 pts/0    S    23:14   0:00 ./a
aa       21818  0.0  0.0   4224  1000 pts/0    S    23:15   0:00 ./a
aa       22160  0.0  0.0   4224   744 pts/0    D    23:15   0:00 ./a
aa       22161  0.0  0.0   4224   744 pts/0    S    23:15   0:00 ./a
aa       22195  0.0  0.0  14224   928 pts/1    S+   23:15   0:00 grep --color=auto ./a
 kill -9 22160
ps aux | grep ./a
www-data 18214  0.0  0.5 830604 10752 ?        Sl   06:25   0:09 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
aa       21818  0.0  0.0   4224  1000 pts/0    S    23:15   0:00 ./a
aa       22161  0.0  0.0   4224  1008 pts/0    S    23:15   0:00 ./a
aa       22430  0.0  0.0  14224  1016 pts/1    S+   23:16   0:00 grep --color=auto ./a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some, but not all, implementations of Unix allow a process in D-state to be terminated by SIGKILL.

It is also possible that the D-state sleep ended just as you typed the 'kill' command.  D-state is not supposed to last very long.

Regardless, you cannot *rely* on a process in D-state being killable by any means short of rebooting the entire computer.  That's why "they" say what they say.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot kill a process which is stuck in un-interruptible D state.  There are two possibilities.  Your process could easily not be stuck, it might just be spending *most* of it's time in un-interuptible D state.

The other possibility is that your process is stuck in a *killable* state.  I expect this shows up as D state, for backwards compatibility.

At least `man ps` does not list a different letter for the killable state.  Nor does `man proc` (`/proc/[pid]/stat`).

> #### [TASK_KILLABLE](https://lwn.net/Articles/288056/) - LWN.net, 2008
>
> > Unix tradition (and thus almost all applications) believe file store writes to be non signal interruptible. It would not be safe or practical to change that guarantee.
>
> So it would seem that we are stuck with the occasional blocked-and-immortal process forever.
>
> Or maybe not. A while back, Matthew Wilcox realized that many of these concerns about application bugs do not really apply if the application is about to be killed anyway. It does not matter if the developer thought about the possibility of an interrupted system call if said system call is doomed to never return to user space. So Matthew created a new sleeping state, called TASK_KILLABLE; it behaves like TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE with the exception that fatal signals will interrupt the sleep.
>
> [...]
>
> The number of places in the kernel (as of 2.6.26-rc8) which are actually using this new state is quite small - as in, one need not worry about running out of fingers while counting them. The NFS client code has been converted, which can only be a welcome development. But there are very few other uses of TASK_KILLABLE, and none at all in device drivers, which is often where processes get wedged.
>
> It can take time for a new API to enter widespread use in the kernel, especially when it supplements an existing functionality which works well enough most of the time.

I happened to notice that TASK_KILLABLE is now also used by balance_dirty_pages(), at least [in Linux v4.19](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/mm/page-writeback.c#L1765).  This is the kernel function that processes block inside, when they fill up the kernel writeback cache.  So I *think* non-synchronous filesystem write() calls are now killable.  (Maybe synchronous ones are as well, I haven't checked).